# How to improve odometry?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am going through the http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Troubleshooting; which is related to proper navigation stack set up?

1. **What do we mean by poor odometry**?
2. **How to resolve the "poor odometry issue"?**
3. **What are the files (and where) that should be look into if navigation stack give rise to abnormal behavior?**

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121151/how-to-improve-odometry?/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-22**:
Poor Odometry means large error in translation and rotation of robot. this helps more http://groups.csail.mit.edu/drl/courses/cs54-2001s/odometry.html

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-01-23**:
@bvbdort  Thank you for sharing the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

About the poor odometry in ROS nav stack from my own experience.

Both gmapping and amcl need the odom message from the robot hardware.

and the /map->/odom tf relation should be static all the running time.

So if the dynamic map generated by the gampping has a drift when robot doing a inplace rotation,

I suppose that means the /map->/odom tf relation has been polluted by the real robot angular odometry output,
even though the /map->/odom tf is published by the gammping or amcl module,
but still need to debug the git source code to confirm the real root causes.

As well as the draft  local costmap when playing with the amcl + static map.

As for the poor translation odometer, I guess a shifting map/local costmap will be its friends.

I do not have any solution about how to improve the hardware odom output via a software mean.

---

Originally posted by [SHI.ZP](https://answers.ros.org/users/25720/shi.zp/) with karma: 30 on 2016-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0